# How to get user description and status?

Tags: discord, discord-jda

how to get user description ("About me") and custom status in [JDA](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA)?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: About me is not visible to bots.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can just use `getUserByID()`. Something like this:

```
import sx.blah.discord.api.IDiscordClient;
import sx.blah.discord.handle.obj.IUser;

// Initiate your 'client' as an instance of IDiscordClient
IDiscordClient client = ...;

// String userId = "1234567890";  // <- Uncomment this for tests.
// Get the user's profile information by some user ID
IUser user = client.getUserByID(userId);

// And then get the user's description and custom status
String description = user.getDescription();
String customStatus = user.getCustomStatus();
```

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for solution in JDA.